# How get details of unexpected sharepoint error?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, iis-6

I have deployed sharepoint solutions. Some of web-parts always cause unexpected error. Some days ago they worked, before installing sharepoint on new server.

[image: error]

I will try to find error details.

- In Central Administration  http://localhost:3442/_admin/metrics.aspx in `Trace Log` C:\program files\common files\Microsoft shared\Web server extensions\12\LOGS  files have not detail.aspx information.
- IIS logs is not contain useful information too
- Windows Event Log is empty
- I switched `<customErrors mode="Off" />` in all `.config` files.

How I can solve this problem? How I can to find details of the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For switch off sharepoint error handler you must to change web.config so as following example

```
<configuration>
<SharePoint>
    <SafeMode MaxControls="200" CallStack="True" DirectFileDependencies="10" 
     TotalFileDependencies="50" AllowPageLevelTrace="True">
```

More information here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231550.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As its a SharePoint error, the first thing to look is to check ULS logs which should be in 12\logs. Its worth installing ULS log viewer on the SharePoint server. Open the log file in it and search test/default.aspx. Check further down, there should be some clue about the error.

ULS log viewer can be downloaded from http://shrptninjatoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/15669

Comment: I saw 12\logs (see question), but there is no information.

Comment: Thanks for viewer. I found sollution without viewer, but it's good answer.